# Why does an element inside another element not disappear when the larger element disappears?

Tags: html, css

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/pWdVyP?editors=1100)

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mynav").style.width = "100vw";
}
 function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mynav").style.width = "0vw";
}
```

```css
 html,body{
    height:100vh;
    background:grey;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    overflow:hidden;
   }
  .item{
  font-size:100px;
  }
  .nav{
  z-index:1;
  height:100%;
  width:0;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:#111;
  transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .open{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  padding:20px;
  font-size:30px;
  }
  .open:hover{
  color:#f1f1f1;
  }
  .close{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  padding:20px;
  color:#818181;
  font-size:60px;
  }
  .close:hover{
  color:#f1f1f1;
  }
```

```html
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite" rel="stylesheet">

<div class='item'>G. Chen's Drawings</div>

<div class='nav' id='mynav'>
 <a class="close" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
 <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24628125/31184132-90a37a5a-a8f6-11e7-89ba-4bc8ca7484d8.png" alt="horse eye" width="200" height="100">
</div>

<span onclick="openNav()" class='open'>&#9776 Gallery</span>
```

The horse eye image is blocking the menu button. But I put the `<img>` inside the side nav `<div>`. WHen the side nav restracts to the left, the horse eye just stays out and doesn't diappear. Why?

You need to remove the `<img>` to see the button for opening the side nav menu. You press the open button and the side nav comes out. I want the horse eye image to be inside the side nav. When the sidenav closes, the image should disppears with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to your styles for `.nav`

Otherwise the overflow (beyond the declared width) will be visible.

**Working Example:**

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mynav").style.width = "100vw";
}
 function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mynav").style.width = "0vw";
}
```

```css
html,body{
    height:100vh;
    background:grey;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    overflow:hidden;
   }
  .item{
  font-size:100px;
  }
  .nav{
  z-index:1;
  height:100%;
  width:0;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:#111;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  .open{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  padding:20px;
  font-size:30px;
  }
  .open:hover{
  color:#f1f1f1;
  }
  .close{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  padding:20px;
  color:#818181;
  font-size:60px;
  }
  .close:hover{
  color:#f1f1f1;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite" rel="stylesheet">

<div class='item'>G. Chen's Drawings</div>

<div class='nav' id='mynav'>
 <a class="close" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
 <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24628125/31184132-90a37a5a-a8f6-11e7-89ba-4bc8ca7484d8.png" alt="horse eye" width="200" height="100">
</div>

<span onclick="openNav()" class='open'>&#9776 Gallery</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the inner element max width of 100%

Answer (score 0):

The `nav` doesn't disappear, it only has `width: 0`, which makes it invisible. But it's still there and serves as the parent for the  "eye". Since that one is absolutely positioned, it can also appear outside the borders of its parent.

Addition:

If you make the nav 100px wide (like here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBqaYE?editors=1100), the eye is still there in its full width - for the same reason: The absolute position makes it independent of the borders of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the width. What you should change is the left position of the nav. Here is a working example https://codepen.io/kingychiu/pen/MEOZMB.

JS:

```
  function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mynav").style.left = "0px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mynav").style.left = "-100vw";
    }
```

CSS:

```
.nav{
  z-index:1;
  height:100%;
  width:100vw;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:-100vw;
  background:#111;
  transition: 0.5s;
  }
```